# Why is my long-standing client's e-mail marked as Spam (and removed) but not Junk? How can I stop this?

Tags: high-sierra, email, spam

In the last week, my client's emails have become lost, and finally found in the Apple Spam folder. What is Spam? Is it a flag coming from my ISP? I don't see any spam settings in Mail Prefs, and don't know how to change it, since it's an e-mail I've been responding to for years.

Thanks for your help!

Apple Mail 11.5 
OS X 10.13.6 High Sierra

Comment: Welcome Greg.  It would be helpful to know what ISP/Email provider you are using.   As @Ezekiel said below, they may be doing spam detection for you.  Do they have a web-based email application, where you can put email addresses in your address-book (on their server)?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Junk and Spam are generally interchangeable terms.

In the Mail app Preferences page, there is a Junk Mail filtering tab. If your email provider does Spam/Junk mail filtering, you should leave this off as it will just be redundant and cause confusion.

Your email provider may mark things as spam/junk and will put them in a Spam/Junk mailbox, which would appear on the sidebar in Mail. You can generally prevent this by dragging emails back to your inbox, but this depends on your email service provider. Mail is only acting as a window into your mailbox, and is not doing any filtering if the above preference I mentioned is turned off.